# Node.js Error: Cannot GET/ from running on the web browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, web-development-server

So here I have 2 route files and 1 controllers for each.
My first router that is root, is working fine !
but my second route that is /teacher is giving me this error "Cannot GET /teacher"
I literally copy pasted the root route code and changed the variable names still its not working.
following are my files:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const root_rt = require('./routes/root-rt');
const teacher_rt = require('./routes/teacherlogin-rt')

dotenv.config();
const uri = process.env.DB_URI;
const port = process.env.PORT;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', root_rt);
app.get('/teacher', teacher_rt);

app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`server started on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**teacherlogin-rt.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const teacherController = require('../controllers/teacher-cnt');

router.route('/')
    .get(teacherController.login);
    
module.exports = router;
```

**teacher-cnt**

```
module.exports.login = function (req, res) {
    res.send('this is teacher login page');
};
```

*Thank you in advance.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using routers, you shouldn't use `app.METHOD()` to mount them, but `app.use()`:

```
app.use('/', root_rt);
app.use('/teacher', teacher_rt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the below change in your teacherlogin-rt.js, it will start working

**teacherlogin-rt.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const teacherController = require('../controllers/teacher-cnt');

router.get('/', teacherController.login);
    
module.exports = router;
```

**server.js**

```
app.use('/', root_rt);
app.use('/teacher', teacher_rt);
```